# LaTeX3 loop expanding to repeated {}s

Tags: loops, latex3

I’m using the [ExPex](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/expex?lang=en) package for vertically aligned linguistics glosses. For various reasons I have some stuff that looks like this:

```
\ex
  \begingl
    \gla \rlap{thisisaverylongword} @ {} @ {} @ {} @ {} @ {} // 
    \glb this- is- a- very- long- word //
    \glb gloss- of- the- word- bits- above //
    \glb \rlap{a.word.that.is.long} {} {} {} {} {} //
  \endgl
\xe
```

It’s tedious to keep writing `@ {}` and `{}` for each column so I’d like to write a macro to emit some number of these empty `{}` cells, with or without the additional `@`. So something like:

```
\ex
  \begingl
    \gla \rlap{thisisaverylongword} \exnull*{5} // 
    \glb this- is- a- very- long- word //
    \glb gloss- of- the- word- bits- above //
    \glb \rlap{a.word.that.is.long} \exnull{5} //
  \endgl
\xe
```

The starred version on the `\gla` line spits out a sequence of five `@ {}` separated by spaces, i.e. `@ {} @ {} @ {} @ {} @ {}`. The unstarred version only emits `{} {} {} {} {}` without any `@`s. I started to do this using LaTeX3 but discovered that the `{}` were being lost and what’s more the spaces were disappearing. Note that I *can’t* use `~` for a space because the space means ‘column separation’ in the `\begingl` macrology and `~` doesn’t.

Any suggestions on a simple do-while loop that emits a number of `{}` and space characters? I have the sinking feeling that `\expandafter` is lurking in the shadows. I’d prefer not to have to muck with ExPex’s internals if I don’t have to; it’s written in plain TeX.

Comment: Please make your code a complete document i.e. it should compile without adding anything to it. Or, if the question is how to solve a compilation error, it should produce that error when people try to compile it. Code fragments are of limited usefulness. **EDIT** Especially if you are going to claim in commentary that the package is called something it is not. `ExPex` is not `expex`. LaTeX looks for completely different `.sty` files.

Comment: I think that `expex` splits the input at spaces when *reading* a `\gla` or `\glb` line. A command like `\exnull` would be seen too late.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `\gla` splits its input at spaces *before* doing expansions. However, no number of `\expandafter`'s can solve the problem, because TeX can't know where `\exnull` will appear.

You can fully expand the line before the scanning for spaces happens, but this can have adverse effects: beware and remember to add `\protect` when necessary.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expex,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\exnull}{sm}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\prg_replicate:nn { #2 } { @~{}~ }}
    {\prg_replicate:nn { #2 } { {}~ }}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter
\def\glw@gla@a #1//{%
  \bgroup
  \protected@edef\JAMES@temp{#1 }%
  \expandafter\ling@usearg\expandafter\glw@gla@b\JAMES@temp\@nil
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\ex
  \begingl
    \gla \rlap{thisisaverylongword} @ {} @ {} @ {} @ {} @ {} // 
    \glb this- is- a- very- long- word //
    \glb gloss- of- the- word- bits- above //
    \glb \rlap{a.word.that.is.long} {} {} {} {} {} //
  \endgl
\xe

\ex
  \begingl
    \gla \rlap{thisisaverylongword} \exnull*{5} // 
    \glb this- is- a- very- long- word //
    \glb gloss- of- the- word- bits- above //
    \glb \rlap{a.word.that.is.long} \exnull{5} //
  \endgl
\xe

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you could, rather than expand the whole line, fetch all the material up to \\, check for an `\exnull`, split, expand the `\exnull` (which will check for a `*`) enough (for example I would use `\xintiloop` for `\exnull` and expand with ``\romannumeral`^^@`` but there must be a `LaTeX3` way), re-permute the material, and then invoke the original `\gla`.